# retrieving node keys if node and properties value knowed in neo4j cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a node v that have  3 properties p1 =  14,p2= 22,and p3=45, how to retrieved properties p1 if node v and value 14 is known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you just want the key on the node where the value = 14?

Something like this might work, assuming that node `v` is already in the scope of the query, and `valueToFind` is a parameter of the query:

```
...
WITH v, filter(key in keys(v) WHERE v[key] = $valueToFind) as keysWithValue
RETURN keysWithValue
```